# KDE .Deskop Exec doesn't return to prompt in terminal

Tags: kde, .desktop

I am trying to add an entry in KDE Menu Editor, that executes a command in terminal, and return to prompt in the opened terminal.

The result: new terminal is opened, the command is executed but no return to prompt, and no response but just closing the terminal (even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> cause no action).
[image]

The command I tried is: `konsole --hold -e "hping --help"`
Adding & at the end didn't help.

How to add a "command to run in terminal and return to prompt" as an entry in the KDE application menu?

Comment: Avoid attaching picture, whenever possible .... use copy-paste instead

Comment: So that deserves a down vote!!

Comment: No, I have not down-voted this. I am a reviewer. Here is [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer:

1. Uncheck the option 'Run in terminal' in KDE Menu Editor
2. Call bash to execute command
3. Append `;$SHELL` to the end

   `konsole  -e "bash -c 'hping --help;$SHELL'"`